# Push Parse query result into an array : JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I need to draw a graph of query results returned by Parse. User will select to dates, then I am creating array of dates present between those two dates and then I am passing that array to parse query.
My code is as follow:

```
var from = $( "#from" ).val(); //to get from value from a form
var to = $( "#to" ).val();  //to get to value from a form

var dates = []; //to store all dates
var data = []; // to store all data  returned by parse
var currentDate = from;
dates.push(from);

while (currentDate != to) {

 var addOne = moment(currentDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").add(1, 'days');
 currentDate = moment(addOne).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
 dates.push(currentDate);

} // to get all dates present between two dates

//using for loop to get data from parse
for(var j = 0; j < dates.length; j++)
  {

    var dateStart = moment(dates[j], "YYYY-MM-DD").startOf('day'); //to get start of day
    var dateEnd = moment(dates[j], "YYYY-MM-DD").endOf('day'); // to get end of day

    var noRequests = Parse.Object.extend("Requests");
    var query = new Parse.Query(noRequests); 

    //then I am using greaterThanOrEqualTo and lessThan to calculate number of request made onn that day
    query.greaterThanOrEqualTo('createdAt', dateStart._d);
    query.lessThan('createdAt', dateEnd._d);

    query.count({
      success: function(count) {

      data.push(count);

      if(data.length == dates.length)
      {
       //passing both array to function which will draw graph using both arrays
        drawGraph(dataArray,dateArray);

      }

    }
    });


  }
```

But due to asynchronous nature of Parse,sometimes I am not getting sequence of results correctly. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Replace the `count` method with `get` and instead of pushing the `count` at the end of the array (hence loosing the order), add it in a dictionary at an uniquely identifying key retrieved from the `success` callback parameter.

Comment: Okay, I will try this and will let you know if it worked or not. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I tried get method instead of count, but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't know the web API, never used it, so I can't help you any further. So read [the guide](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries) and [the documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html) and try harder.

Answer (score 0):

Putting requests in a loop is always a bad idea. Im also surprised that this works at all considering that you arent returning any promises from this. You will need to use `var _ = require("underscore");` for this, but it will ensure that your promises are executed in the correct order.

This is also not the way to start a parse request. Instead of using

```
var noRequests = Parse.Object.extend("Requests");
var query = new Parse.Query(noRequests);
```

You should use:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Request");
```

If you really want to loop this request, you will need to do something such as:

```
var promises = _.map(dates, function(date){
    var dateStart = moment(dates[j], "YYYY-MM-DD").startOf('day'); //to get start of day
    var dateEnd = moment(dates[j], "YYYY-MM-DD").endOf('day'); // to get end of day
    var query = new Parse.Query("Request");
    query.greaterThanOrEqualTo('createdAt', dateStart._d);
    query.lessThan('createdAt', dateEnd._d);
    return query.count()
        .then(function(count){
            data.push(count);
        }, function (error){
            console.error(error);
        });
    });
```